# LVDT that is not an LVDT

Tags: sensor, transducer

I have been given a specification for an LVDT transducer where I was expecting a clear Va, Vb relationship. The Va and Vb are however described as having a phase and an non-linear relationship (i.e. Sin/Cosine ArcTan). Is this likely to be a resolver on a cam or some specially wound LVDT? (i.e are any LVDTs specially wound to produce an emulated resolver waveform?)

Comment: Can you reproduce the full spec?

Comment: I'll see what I can do to obfuscate the details ... to give the general profile of the Va/Vb characteristics. I am sure I don't have permission to duplicate the full spec.

Comment: `L` in LVDT stands for Linear.  It's Linear Motion, not the Linear Output, I think.

Comment: The spec says LVDT, so the action is clearly linear, but the output is strangely not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaahh !

Ratiometric v Differential

5 wire ratiometeric ratio = (Va-Vb)/(Va+vb)

4 wire Differential (phase relationship)

http://www.pennyandgiles.com/getattachment/Support/Frequently-Asked-Questions/How-does-LVDT-technology-work/LVDT-Technology.pdf

Sorry for bothering you all.

Answer (score 1):

LVDT's are fairly linear - away from their mid-stroke position. But at mid-stroke there is commonly  distortion in the linearity - the 'null' nonlinearity.

To avoid this you can spec an LVDT that is twice the required stroke and operate it either side from null (mid-stroke). There is also nonlinear divergence at end of travel - either end.

Apart from that the core and coil windings are never perfect and so "linearity" has to be considered to what you demand from your application. Although not perfectly linear, the LVDT may offer higher repeatability, so you can always calibrate using a more accurate external sensor, develope a fit correction model and correct your readings on the fly.